# Android Azure notification hub SDK is not working in Android Pie

Tags: android, azure, azure-notificationhub

Android Azure notification hub SDK is not working in Android Pie.

**Below are the SDK details:**

mavel url: "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"

**dependencies:**

`compile 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.4@aar'`

```
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Receive GCM/FCM token
2. Create instance of NotificationHub
3. Call method "registerTemplate" using the instance of NotificationHub along with the required parameters.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/net/http/AndroidHttpClient;
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.Connection.executeRequest(Connection.java:217)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.Connection.executeRequest(Connection.java:178)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.Connection.executeRequest(Connection.java:134)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub.refreshRegistrationInformation(NotificationHub.java:296)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub.registerInternal(NotificationHub.java:390)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub.registerTemplate(NotificationHub.java:196)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in Android Pie the reference for httpclient has removed completly from system ClassLoader. Above issue can be fixed if we add the httpclient as a part of application ClassLoader. I have added

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

inside application tag of manifest file, it's working now. 
For more information please refer below link:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

Answer (score 2):

Update your [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) to the latest version will fix the problem. Along with that, a clean and rebuild of the project and a restart of Android Studio could also help.

Comment: I am using latest version of support library and google play services library.  The SDK uses AndroidHttpClient for network operations, this API is deprecated in Android 6 and removed completely in Android 9.

Comment: try this `android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}` add this in build.gradle

Comment: I am afraid there is any solution to it. Read here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#apache-nonp

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the 0.5 version of Azure Notification Hub Android SDK.

Update your Azure dependency to:

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.5@aar'
```

This version uses `HttpUrlConnection` instead of the legacy `HttpClient`. See pull request: https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/pull/48